# Finding the min and max of $f(x) = \log_{10}x + x^3 - x^2 - 6x + 3$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, logarithms

$$f(x) = \log_{10}x + x^3 - x^2 - 6x + 3$$
$$x > 0$$

How do I find the maxima and the minima of this function?

This is a highscool level problem.

Comment: Not easily.  You have a cubic equation with one irrational coefficient.

Comment: @Lior What's your goal exactly? This is probably a big mess to solve. Why do you need to solve it?

Comment: You will have to use numerical methods to solve this cubic.

Comment: @TonyK What about solving $3x^3-2x^2-6x+\ln (10)=0$?

Comment: @GitGud there's a small typo in your comment. isn't it 1/ln(10)?

Comment: @user57 Yes, you're right.

Comment: I edited my original question, thanks.

Comment: @GitGud: Yes, you're probably right $-$ the direct solution may be faster than a Newton method. But now the question has changed beyond recognition, so it's back to square one.

Comment: @TonyK Well, the old function was actually the derivative of the updated one, so it's basically still the same question, I just thought I might of simplified it in a wrong way.

Comment: Yes, Lior, you simplified it in the wrong way. What we see now is unrelated to the initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are stuck using numerical methods for this problem.

It you look at a plot, you see some of the behaviors.

[image]

If we take the first derivative, we have:

$\displaystyle \tag 1 \frac{d}{dx} (\log_{10}(x)+x^3-x^2-6 x+3) = 3 x^2-2 x+ \frac{1}{x log(10)}-6$

To find the critical points, we have to resort to numerical methods. If those are allowed we find three of them (discard one because it is negative and the problem only asks for positive $x$).

Set the derivative in $(1)$ equal to zero and find the $x$ values as $x = 0.0708856 $ and $x = 1.75768$.

We see (local max and min - no global max and min):

- $\max~~\{\log_{10}(x)+x^3-x^2-6 x+3\} ~~\text{is}~~ 1.42058 ~~\text{at}~~ x = 0.0708856$
- $\min~~\{\log_{10}(x)+x^3-x^2-6 x+3\} ~~ \text{is}~~ -4.96033 ~~\text{at}~~ x= 1.75768$

Comment: Nicely Done +1..

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend - always nice to receive positive feedback (and negative if deserved).

Comment: I have seen from your side just ++++

Comment: You are too kind!

Comment: The thing is - how do I solve the equation using highschool methods?

Comment: @Lior: They can find the derivative, plot the derivatives function and then try values of x until finding a suitable one at points where the function crosses the x-axis. Regards

Comment: Helpful, Amzoti!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks!